# Closing multiple id channels of file descriptors fd[i][2]

Tags: c

```
void helper(int *fd, int *total) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < (*total); i++) {
    close(fd[i][0]);
      }
}
```

Below is what my pseudo code looks like which forks multiple children and pipes, after all child process finish reading, they call the helper function to close the read end of the channels.

```
int main() {
    .
    int fd[4][2]
   .
   .
   .
   if (fork()==0) {
      helper(&(fd[4][2]), &i)
```

I am getting an error that states:

```
error: subscript value is neither an array nor pointer nor vector
```

edit:typo "for()" to "fork()"

Comment: `if ( for() == 0 )` is a syntax error

Comment: My bad, typo, my eyes are half shut lol.

Answer (score 1):

`int *fd` is a dimension array's pointer, so you can not reference its item as tow dimension array like this:  `fd[i][0]`.

Again `fd[4][2]` is wrong for array access because of `[4][2]` is out of bound.

Comment: If you want to pass the entire `fd` array to `helper` then the function declaration must be: `void helper(int (*fd)[2], int *total)`, or `void helper(int (*p_fd)[4][2], int *total)` and you pass to it `fd` or `&fd` respectively.

Comment: How is fd[4][2] out of bound? I thought the first array is like an id for all the different process to keep track of, no? Besides thanks for the reply

Comment: Hey got it working, declaring function as (*fd)[2] works. Thanks

Comment: `int fd[4][2]` shows that the last item in `fd` is `fd[3][1]`, the first item is `fd[0][0]`.